# Undefined control sequence and Double superscript in my equation

Tags: amsmath

I become an error that says Undefined control sequence and Double superscript. I don't understand what is the Problem exactly, but I obtain exactly what I need for my equation. I just can't get rid of the error

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:one}
\begin{split}
\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }\sum _{\kappa =0}^{\infty }x\left[\kappa \right]\cdot g\left[k-\kappa \right]  \cdot z^{-k} & = \sum _{\kappa =0}^{\infty }\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }x\left[\kappa \right]\cdot g\left[k-\kappa \right]  \cdot z^{-k}\\
& = \sum _{k=0}^{\infty }x\left[\kappa \right]\cdot \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } g\left[k-\kappa \right] \cdot z^{-k} \cdot z^{\kappa} \cdot z^{-\kappa} \\
& = \sum _{k=0}^{\infty }x\left[\kappa \right]\cdot z^{-\kappa}\cdot \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } g\left[k-\kappa \right] \cdot z^{-k} \cdot z^{\kappa} \cdotz^{-(k-\kappa)}\\
& = \sum _{k=0}^{\infty }x\left[\kappa \right]\cdot z^{-\kappa}\cdot \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } g\left[n\right] \cdot z^{-n} = G(z) \cdot X(z)
\end{split}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Replace `\cdotz` with `\cdot z`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a `\cdotz` instead of a `\cdot z` at the end of the penultimate line.

I'll add that your first line is too long to place correctly the equation number. I suggest to load `mathtools` (needless to load `amsmath` in this case), remove the `&` in this line and replace it  with `\MoveEqLeft` at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to fixing the typo, i.e., replacing `\cdotz` with `\cdot z`, you should give searious consideration to getting rid of all 17 `\cdot` directives as well as the 10 `\left` and 10 `\right` directives. The latter two do *absolutely nothing* except insert unnecessary whitespace.

In a separate matter, I would replace the `split` environment with an `aligned[b]` environment, to permit placement of the equation number on the bottom row.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:nnn}
\begin{aligned}[b]
\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }\sum _{\kappa =0}^{\infty }x[\kappa ] \,g[k-\kappa ] z^{-k} 
&= \sum _{\kappa =0}^{\infty }\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }x[\kappa ] \,g[k-\kappa ] z^{-k}\\
&= \sum _{k=0}^{\infty }x[\kappa ] \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } g[k-\kappa ] z^{-k} z^{\kappa} z^{-\kappa} \\
&= \sum _{k=0}^{\infty }x[\kappa ] z^{-\kappa} \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } g[k-\kappa ] z^{-k} z^{\kappa} z^{-(k-\kappa)}\\
&= \sum _{k=0}^{\infty }x[\kappa ] z^{-\kappa} \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } g[n] z^{-n} = G(z) X(z)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is `\cdotz` that should be `\cdot z`.

However there are other problems.

1. Generally speaking, `\cdot` is not used.
2. `\left` and `\right` in the use case only add unwanted space.
3. Parentheses are missing.
4. The indices of a few summations are wrong.

I suggest to move the last item in a separate line, because it's the most important thing, that is, the conclusion. With a suitable phantom, we can easily make the last equals sign at the same distance as the others.

Finally, a small adjustment: you may notice that `\kappa=0` and `k=0` are not aligned in subscripts. Instead of the heavy `\vphantom{k}\kappa`, I suggest a specific command for this case.

For the parentheses, I use `\biggl(` and `\biggr), because` \left(`and`\right)`would choose too big a size. Since the end of`\biggl(` is too near to the subscript, a thin space is added.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\adjkappa}{\vphantom{k}\kappa}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq:one}
\begin{split}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}
\sum _{\adjkappa =0}^{\infty}
  x[\kappa] g[k-\kappa] z^{-k}
& = \sum_{\adjkappa =0}^{\infty}
    \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}
      x[\kappa] g[k-\kappa] z^{-k}
\\
& = \sum_{\adjkappa=0}^{\infty}x[\kappa]
    \biggl(\,
    \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}
      g[k-\kappa] z^{-k} z^{\kappa} z^{-\kappa}
    \biggr)
\\
& = \sum_{\adjkappa=0}^{\infty} x[\kappa] z^{-\kappa}
    \biggl(\,
    \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} g[k-\kappa] z^{-(k-\kappa)}
    \biggr)
\\
& = \biggl(\,
    \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} g[n] z^{-n}
    \biggr)
    \biggl(\,
    \sum_{\adjkappa=0}^{\infty}x[\kappa] z^{-\kappa}
    \biggr)
\\
& = G(z) X(z) \vphantom{\smash[b]{\sum^{\infty}}}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Note that the last two summations are reversed, because this reflects the algebraic step (and also the conclusion with *G* in front of *X*).

I also fixed a mistake in the third line.

[image]